# Normal neighborhood and orthonormal frame

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, and $p \in M$, $(x^i)$ is a normal coordinate of $p$. Then does $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\}$ constitute an orthonormal frame of $M$.

I can show that at point $p$, $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p\}$ is an orthnormal basis. But what about it being evaluated at other points in the normal neighborhood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not unless $M$ is flat on the domain of the chart $(x^i)$ - the coordinate frame being orthonormal means exactly that $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$. In general the best you can do is "orthonormal to first order", since we have $$g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + C R_{ikjl} x^k x^l + o(|x|^2).$$

Comment: Consider the radial vector field (take the normal coordinate chart around $p$)$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}:= \frac{x^i}{r(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ where $r(x)  = \sqrt{\sum (x^i)^2}$. In Lee's Riemannian Manifolds, he cliams that the radial vector field is a unit vector field. It is certainly of unit length at $p$, but how can one conclude that it is of unit length at other points if the coordinate frame does not constitute an orthonormal frame?

Comment: @z.z: this is a consequence of the definition of normal coordinates - the lines $x^i = t v^i$ are geodesics with constant speed $|v|$, and you should be able to prove that $\partial/\partial r|_{y}$ is the velocity vector of the line with $v = y/r(y)$.